# Laravel 5.1 xmlHttpRequest AJAX POST TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

The relevant code is shown below:

```
var csrfToken = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/internal/v1/create/strategy", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
postString = "param1=" + varOne + "&param2=" + varTwo;
xmlhttp.send(postString);
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, I honestly have no idea what to do at this point. Note, that if I use the form method everything works just fine. I've also tried sending the CSRF token as a parameter in the postString: "_token=" + csrfToken

Comment: Have you tried with `X-XSRF-TOKEN`?

Comment: Did you try to debug the post request to see if the headers actually get transmitted? Also I can't see how you instantiate your xmlhttp object.

Comment: The xmlhttp object is instantiated normally earlier in the code, but I was able to fix the code. There were two issues at play here, in the config/session.php file the domain was set to null, I read somewhere that this needs to be setup or else it causes errors so I did that, but additionally I needed to include the content-type as url-encoded form.

Comment: Are you using `PHP` to echo the token in a `JavaScript` variable? use something like `<meta name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` and then try accessing it in your `JavaScript`.

Comment: I was, and still am. I've gotten the code itself to work though based on the fixes I mentioned above.

Comment: @jrgilman - if you've resolved your own issue, then please post your solution.

Comment: @BrynJ was going to as soon as it lets me, currently its still locking me out of answering my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved via a two-part solution:

It was necessary to add the 'Content-type' header for the Laravel to be able to read the POST'ed parameters:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Additionally, in the config/session.php file it was necessary to also point the 'domain' variable towards the actual domain of the application, rather than the default value of null. This is probably something that's done during initial setup, but I must have forgot to do so.

After making both of these changes, the POST request would successfully go through via AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still struggle with the above answer, You can try this below.

```
var token = $("#token").val();
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "upload/media/files?_token="+token);
```

While the $("#token).val() is already inside a hidden input see example below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="token">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', group_email_url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      if (data['status']==true) {
         window.location = group_list_url;
      } else {
         alert('Whoops Something went wrong!!');
        }
      }
     }
xhr.send('group_id=' + group_id + '&ids=' + strIds);
```